# Field required a bean which could not be found in springboot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, aerospike

I am creating a basic spring boot REST API. My project has the following structure:

> > com.anonreporting.springboot
> >      --- SpringBootAnonReporting.java , config.java
> >
> > com.anonreporting.springboot.controller -- userController.java
> >
> > com.anonreporting.springboot.domain -- User.java
> >
> > com.anonreporting.springboot.service -- UserService.java UserServiceImpl.java
> >
> > com.anonreporting.springboot.repository -- userRepository.java

SpringBootAnonReporting.java

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAnonReporting {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAnonReporting.class, args);

        for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

User.java is a POJO class.

UserController

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/users",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<Iterable<User>> listAllUsers()
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<Iterable<User>>(userService.listAllUsers(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/newuser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity registerUser(User user)
    {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/get",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<String> tryGet()
    {
        System.out.println("hihihih");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("HI",HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

UserService:

```
@Service
public interface UserService {

    Iterable<User> listAllUsers();

    User getUserById(String id);

    User saveUser(User user);

    void deleteUser(String id);


}
```

UserServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;



    @Override
    public Iterable<User> listAllUsers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        userRepository.delete(id);

    }

}
```

config.java

```
@Configurable
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {
    public @Bean(destroyMethod = "close") AerospikeClient aerospikeClient() {

        ClientPolicy policy = new ClientPolicy();
        policy.failIfNotConnected = true;
        policy.timeout = 2000;

        return new AerospikeClient(policy, "172.28.128.3", 3000);
    }

    public @Bean AerospikeTemplate aerospikeTemplate() {
        return new AerospikeTemplate(aerospikeClient(), "test");
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java:

```
@Component
public interface UserRepository extends AerospikeRepository<User, String> {

}
```

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>anonReporting</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>anonReporting</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aerospike/aerospike-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
            <artifactId>aerospike-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aerospike/spring-data-aerospike -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-aerospike</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
         </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-keyvalue -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-keyvalue</artifactId>

        </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

On running the code, the following error occurs:

```
  ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.anonreporting.springboot.user.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.anonreporting.springboot.user.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.anonreporting.springboot.user.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

**What I have tried:**

- All other packages are a sub package of com.anonreporting.springboot, so i don't have to use component scan for them (correct me if i am wrong).
- I have tried with componentScan as well with no success.
- Moving everything in same package does help, but i want to structure it in this way only. I am using areospike with spring boot.
- I have tried changing versions of dependencies also.

Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: where is UserRepository.java?

Comment: Have you created your UserRepository class ?

Comment: Forgot to add the userRepository while posting the question, i had it in my code. I have edited the question, kindly review it.

Comment: Maybe you should just switch up the annotation in UserRepository from `@Component ` to `@Repository` since UserRepository.java is a repository

Comment: @S.Tushinov, I tried changing that, but still get the same error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was with pom.xml only. I just replaced my pom with the following and everything worked.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>anonReporting</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>anonReporting</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-aerospike</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see you have not created UserRepository.java. Spring can not Autowire something that does not exist so you can try creating it in a package that is convenient for you. It should look something like this

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{}
```

Comment: Forgot to add the userRepository while posting the question, i had it in my code. I have edited the question, kindly review it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change annotation in your `UserRepository.class` from `@Component` to `@Repository` as spring-data is scanning for `@Repository` annotations.

Comment: I tried changing that, but still get the same error